# Why I can not get the updated "cars" array in my new popped up window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

My ***index.html*** has a button(`id="my-btn"`):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>My INDEX PAGE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br><input type="button" id="my-btn" value="OPEN NEW WINDOW"/>
        <script src="js/my.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

above page include ***my.js*** which handles button click event, when button clicked, a new browser window will be opened with a new page(***test.html***)

**my.js:**

```
$('#my-btn').click(function(){  
  window.open('test.html', 'testwindow');
});
```

The new page (***test.html***) opened/popped up in new browser window:
**test.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cars"></div>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mycar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/test.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the new page, **test.js** is included which will call functions in `MyTest` and append the text of number of cars as the content of this pop-up page:

**js/test.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    MyTest.updateCars(); //MyTest is a function defined in mycar.js
    var cars = MyTest.getCars(); 
$("#cars").append("<strong>number of cars: "+cars.length+"</strong>");
});
```

Function `MyTest` is defined in **mycar.js:**

**js/mycar.js**

```
var MyTest = function(){
    var cars=[];

    var updateCars=function(){
        cars.push('car 1', 'car 2');
    };

    return{
        updateCars: function(){
            updateCars();
        },
        getCars: function(){
            console.log(cars.length);
            return cars;
        }
    };
}();
```

But, when the **test.html** page popped up in a new browswer window, the number of cars is always 0.

As you saw above I have called `updateCars()` function of ***mycar.js*** in ***test.js*** but the pop up window does not show the updated cars number , how can I get the updated cars(that's 2 cars, car1 and car2) in the new popped up window?

(I have jquery-1.5.1.js under "js/" directory)

Comment: Done, and some response regards to my question?

Answer (score 1):

hey i pasted your code in a page and it displayed

```
 number of cars: 2
```

it seems to work are you just referencing the script wrong?
have you tried the debugger on chrome or firebug?

Comment: megakorre is right, see: http://jsbin.com/aguya4 your script is fine, you likely have a script include that isn't working properly.